# How to map SQLSTATE values to their meaning?

Tags: sql, database

How do I map [SQLSTATE values](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v5r3/index.jsp?topic=/rzala/rzalaco.htm) to their meaning in Java?

Comment: The concept of SQLSTATE isn't related to Java really. Do you mean using the JDBC API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the JDBC API, you can get the SQLSTATE of a database exception using `SQLException.getSQLState()`.

Other Java APIs (for example JPA) don't know about the SQLSTATE as far as I know.

There is no API to get the *meaning* of a specific SQLSTATE. For that you will have to look up in the SQL specification, or even better in the database documentation, as it sometimes depends on the database type which SQLState you get for which exception.

Comment: No, I'm afraid not. Some databases have a central documentation for SQL states / exceptions codes and their meaning however - but typically that's online and not within the product itself.